# How to share a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

First is it dumb to use DJango as a quick/dirty data access method?  We have a backend process that will be feeding a GUI which will be implemented with django, and we figured we could just share a model between them.  We dont care about performance the backend process just needs a quick way to throw something in a DB.

Assuming is not dumb how to we go about sharing a model between a UI and Backend process?

Right now we have the "model" defined we just dont know where it should reside.  We tried putting it in the backend process in a model package, but since its an app we can't really generate the SQL for it.

We also tried just creating a models.py and importing our models but it doesn't generate any sql.

Behind the scenes I know it uses[app_name]_[table/model] for the db table name, so are we trying to do something we shouldn't?

Really would like to know the correct way to use a shared django model. Any help would be appreciated.

I currently have defined the model outside of the ui, and I am trying to find out how to reference them in the "app" so that when I call manage.py sql app  it generates my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're hooked up to the database in question in your settings file, and the model defines fields that exist on the table, you just need to set the `db_table` meta option to refer to the actual table name and the SQL generated via the ORM should return results / attempt to update the table.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table

Then, it's just a matter of importing that model and using the ORM. As Ignacio linked to, you will have to specify `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` for django to know which settings file to use for your model.

PS: Awesome stuff in that post, I didn't know there was an shortcut for setting up the environment!

Comment: THis works, but if I declare the model in a package outside of the app, how do i generate the SQL for it?     I tried to just import the model classes in the models.py inside of the app but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: That's fine. Are you getting an exception?

Comment: No it just didn't do anything, so i copied all the code from the package pasted in the app, and then just ran the command to generate the tables... just wondering  the correct way to do it?